# What is the best practice to create an AJAX navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, .htaccess

I'm trying to build a website which doesn't reload all the page each time the user press the link of the navbar. So I'm using jQuery and AJAX with GET to load the corresponding html file in a div tag.

Then I need to change the URL so I can use to write it the code below:

```
 history.pushState()
```

And to read it:

```
location.href()
```

I'll modify my *htaccess* to redirect the urls like:

```
mysite.com/home
mysite.com/contact
```

to my only html file that I have where it'll be readed and then loaded.

My questions are: this would work ok? This is the best way to do it or you'd modify, remove or add something?

Any help or advice you can give would be apreciated and if you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Comment: Why would you use jQuery to read window.location.href? Seems weird.

Comment: well, I use it for another things to... so the library is already added.

Comment: @Joëlle — `location.href` is less code and fewer function calls than `$(location).attr('href');` which doesn't even make sense because `location` isn't an HTML element node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirecting to a single URI and then rebuilding the page with JavaScript misses the point of using the history API - which is to have real URLs that don't depend on JavaScript, are good for linking to (without loading an interstitial page before pulling in content with JS - which used to be Twitter's problem and is why they moved to the history API) and are good food for search engines.

Comment: @quintin I was wondering about this also. If I have a page that would load articles through javaScript it would still be needed to have server side logic to link to these articles directly with (for example) http://www.mysite.org/20130105/goog for SEO and users wanting to bookmark to that article directly?

Comment: Yes. See [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: +1 for the references. I guess mv(something) frameworks like symfony cater to solve this problem by enabling different responses/controllers when ajaxcall is made. You could then render only part of a template so JS can set the content of part of the page.

Comment: Thanks all you for the anwers. So with the history api I have to preload all the content of the page, this is what are you saying?

Comment: No. You don't need to preload anything. When a page is first loaded the various parts of it should be assembled with server side code and not client side code.